Viewing component data in PDF schematic
I have a schematic (PDF) where each component has some data like part number, value and so on. My question is how can this data accessed? I tried the built-in PDF viewer on Edge and PDF X but I haven't been able to do it.
Any help would be apreciated, thank you,
Burek

Can you explain what how can this data accessed? means and/or give a link to an example schematic? E.g. I have seen some schematics published in PDF format whereby the component data such as part number or reference designator is graphics and therefore can't be copied as text, but I'm not sure if this question is about something else.

Like some metadata of a component, it isn't visible but is supposed to be accessible in some way. Like hovering with your mouse over the component and it would appear (I tries this but it didn't work).

Hello and welcome ... if you can share the PDF we might be able to help, otherwise we're really just guessing, as there are any number of things which are possible with PDF.  Or if you know it, what software made the PDF.

I’m voting to close this question because it's not specifically about EE rather, it's more to do with what information that might be contained (hidden or visible) in a pdf file.

@SMD_Burek From an EE point of view, I curious to know what CAD program created the PDF format schematic. Taking the example of KiCad, according to Schematics plotting to PDF and Javascript there is a difference if the PDF schematic is printed (smaller size and no component data) or plotted (larger size and can contain component data).

@ChesterGillon that's really helpful, I didn't know that.

Altium also has a difference in that regard - IIRC it's linked to terminology in the same way as @ChesterGillon describes with KiCad

Anwsering myself because I managed to find the solution. The phrase I was looking for was a tagged PDF. Components (resistors, transistors and such) have invisible properties that need a left click on the component and then selecting Properties. Online viewers and such couldn't do that, at best they would outline components but were unable to open their properties. Adobe Acrobat does the job.
Thanks regardless,
Burek
